# Why does JAXRS Jersey create temp directories on the app server?

Tags: weblogic, jersey

I am running Jersey on a weblogic server and I noticed a few extra folders were created. The folders look like this,

```
n179u/.tld_cache/jersey-server-1.0.3.1.jar/META-INF/taglib.tld
```

and contain the files

```
crc.ser and des.ser
```

So, my question is what are these directories used for and is it possible to tell jersey to create them in a different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the extension .ser of the files in the folder, my guess is that it is serializing state.